# How is O(n log n) different then O(log n)?

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o

Researching big O notation, I understand the concept of O(log n) as a binary search and O(n log n) as a quick sort.

Can anyone put into layman's terms what the main difference in ***runtime*** is between these two? and why that is the case?

they seem intuitively to be similarly related

Comment: They're quite different: http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Comment: Since `n log n` is a different function from `log n`, one which grows much quicker, why should they be the same? That `n` makes a big difference: if the `log` is base 2 and `n = 1000`, `n log n` is `9965.8` but `log n` is just `9.97`.

Comment: why the downvotes if there are comments?

Comment: I don't know about the downvotes. Many on Stack Overflow seem to have less patience than in the past.

Comment: i think im having trouble understanding how quicksort and binary search are different they seem very much the same

Comment: This question is **definitely not** too broad. It is a specific question with a specific answer. The closing of this question is unjust.

Comment: Maybe "too broad" is the wrong marker here, but that question still qualifies for  beeing closed: CS question with no direct connection to programming and an obvious lack of research (researching bigO means: reading the definitions!; the mapping of log n -> binary-search + n log n -> quick sort is not only wrong, it would also be dangerous if it would be correct, if understanding bigO notation is the goal). (I would also expect that there are hundreds of similar questions already)

Comment: can you please elaborate on why the mapping is wrong?

Comment: First of all: the mapping itself should not be done. You should understand the theoretical concept of bigO-notation and not learn some simple examples for different function-examples. More important: deterministic quicksort has a worst-case of N^2. And that's exactly what is analyzed by bigO.

Comment: can you please provide a link to documentation with theoretical concepts and no examples thank you

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Basically: a factor of N.
A binary search only touches a small number of elements. If there's a billion elements, the binary search only touches ~30 of them.
A quicksort touches every single element, a small number of times. If there's a billion elements, the quick sort touches *all* of them, about 30 times: about 30 billion touches total.

Comment: is the use case for binary search that the input has to be ordered where as quicksort is the best case for random input?

Comment: A binary search finds a value in an ordered list.  A quicksort is a way to sort a list. They aren't really related to each other at all.

Comment: ok i see what your saying...i think i needed to know that binary search has to have ordered input

Comment: Just a minor nitpick: It's 20, not 30

Comment: @NiklasB.: whoops. switched to "billion" where 30 is still accurate.

Comment: I don't think this is a great answer. The part _"Basically: a factor of N."_ is disdainful. I'm sure everyone can see that the difference between Log(n) and n* Log(n) is the factor of N.

Answer (score 27):

[image]

See how `Log(n)` is flat (not literally but figuratively, in comparison to other functions), while `nLog(n)` has crossed 600 for a value of n = 100. That's how different they are.

Comment: `Log(n)` isn't _quite_ flat.

Comment: My point was that the answer says it _is_ flat. Needs a qualifier there.

Comment: All logs are proportional to each other, so in big-O the base doesn't really matter. Nevertheless, it is base 2 which pops up when analyzing divide-and-conquer algorithms, hence using base 2 in the graph would give a better rough idea of the relative run-times for smaller examples.

Comment: I see It is a helpful graph.

Answer (score -5):

On simple terms and visualization, they are kind of the same in sorting algorithms, but quick sort as **O(n log n)** has a flaw in some situations, Quick Sort most situations is **log n**, but on special cases is **n²**, that's why **n** before **log n** . So Quick sort for small amount of sorting is very good, but for millions/billions its not, better use **Merge Sort** for that kind of sorting.

Comment: Or, since quicksort is much faster than merge sort, use [Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) instead, which is usually as fast as quicksort, but doesn't go to n^2.

Comment: "Quick Sort most situations is log n, but on special cases is n², that's why n before log n" makes little sense. Did you really want to say that? Quicksort is *never* `log n` and there is no general theorem that says that if an algorithm is `O(n^2)` worst case then the average complexity is `O(n log n)` -- this is a very special property of quicksort.

Comment: Seems you are confusing orders. A *log N* order is a just a fraction of *N* (often a little one because the base of the logarithm is 2 if you divide *N* recursively in half). A sort can't be performed without at least checking all the *N* elements of the array, so *N* is the lowest order limit.